# Setting var to a nested HTML elements text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to get the value of "nested" from "toplevel" and subtract it from "total". I'm sure my code is mega inefficient, forgive me.

HTML:

```
  <span class="toplevel"> 
    Clickable
    <span class="nested"> 50 </span>
</span> <br>

All put together is...
<div id="total">
  9999
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalcp = parseInt("9999", 10);
  $('#total').text(totalcp).toString();
  $('.toplevel').click(function() {
      var cpcost = ('.nested');
    totalcp = totalcp - cpcost; 
    $('#total').text(totalcp).toString();
  });
});
```

My main problem is the line:

```
var cpcost = ('.nested');
```

I know I'm just missing something stupid!!!! Thanks in advance.

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/ffxivguild/pen/RRkAjV) - of the above combo, the problem is, again, that var cpcost does not get the "nested" value. If replaced with a flat number it works fine.

Comment: Oh dear god I just answered my own question editing that line and adding:  <br/>
      `var cpcost = $('.nested').text();`  <br/>
      `parseInt(cpcost, 10);`  <br/>

However, if there are multiple objects with the class 'toplevel' how can I add a "this" or tell that variable cpcost to 

BUT I AM SURE my code is hellishly inefficient so any advice in general would be nice.

Comment: Oh good ... I just started to get some gray hair over this code

Comment: I can't even format the above comment properly, I apologize profusely for the melanin loss in your hair! I've been away from coding for quite a while, as you may see (15 years...), and this is my very first chunk of real code in a while, bare with me! any and all advice is appreciated.  I guess my next point of confusion would be within multiple cases of a 'toplevel' class, how do I tell that variable to use the 'nested' within "THIS"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You forgot to add `$` in the following code:

```
var cpcost = ('.nested');
```

Replace that with the following code should work:

```
var cpcost =parseInt( $(this).find('.nested').text() );
```

To find `.nested` in the current clicked span (`.toplevel`), simply you can use `$(this)`. By doing this you limit the query to the clicked element. Also, to find a specific element simply you can use `find` function in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you... I managed to find my stupidity a few minutes after posting. But my follow-up question was answered by your code (telling it to look at "this" and how to "find"... thank you.